# React Bootstrap Nav bar Home tab always appears to be highlighted

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am dipping my toes into react and bootstrap for the first time and I came across a simple issue that I cannot seem to figure out. So when I run the website the home tab is highlighted which is great I want it to do this. However when I click on another tab the other tab will be highlighted as well as the home tab. How can I fix this so only one tab is highlighted at one time? I will add most of my code so you guys can see what's all going on. Thanks in advance!

[image: Nav bar]

This picture represents if I click on about us and as you can see the home is highlighted as well I only want one tab to be highlighted at a time.

My App class

```
import './App.css';
import Main from './components/Main.js';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main class that handles nav

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import AboutUs from './AboutUs';
import Services from './Services';
import ContactUs from './ContactUs';


const Main = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/AboutUs' component={AboutUs}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/Services' component={Services}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/ContactUs' component={ContactUs}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Nav bar class

```
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import {Navbar, Nav, Link, } from "react-bootstrap";

function TopNavBar() {

    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav>
              <LinkContainer to="/">
                <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/AboutUs">
                <Nav.Link>About us</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/Services">
                <Nav.Link>Services</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/ContactUs">
                <Nav.Link>Contact us</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
  
  export default TopNavBar;
```

Home class - currently the home, about us, contact us, and services class all look the same but have a different h1 header

```
import  TopNavBar  from './Navbar.js';

function Home() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <TopNavBar> </TopNavBar>
        <h1> Home </h1>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
  
  export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I get rid of my home tab and put a link container for the home screen around the Navbar.brand it will work as expected but I am not sure if it is quite the answer I am looking for.

```
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import {Navbar, Nav} from "react-bootstrap";

function TopNavBar() {

    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav>
              <LinkContainer to="/AboutUs">
                <Nav.Link>About us</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/Services">
                <Nav.Link>Services</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/ContactUs">
                <Nav.Link>Contact us</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
  
  export default TopNavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `exact` to the `LinkContainer` or use an `IndexLinkContainer`

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/issues/151